# i can't install sonataAdminBundle with symfony 5

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-sonata, symfony5

I am trying to install sonata admin bundle in a fresh Symfony 5 installation but I get this error :

```
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install sonata-project/admin-bundle 3.56.1
    - Conclusion: remove twig/twig v3.0.0
    - Installation request for sonata-project/admin-bundle ^3.56 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/admin-bundle[3.56.0, 3.56.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v3.0.0
    - sonata-project/admin-bundle 3.56.0 requires twig/twig ^2.10 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.11.1, v2.11.2, v2.11.3, v2.12.0, v2.12.1, v2.12.2].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.10.0, v3.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.11.0, v3.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.11.1, v3.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.11.2, v3.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.11.3, v3.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.12.0, v3.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.12.1, v3.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.12.2, v3.0.0].
    - Installation request for twig/twig (locked at v3.0.0) -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v3.0.0].
```

Comment: It looks like you have conflicting requirements for Twig. Depending on your use case you might be able to downgrade twig to a `^2.10` instead of using `^3.0` if it will not cause conflicts with other libraries. Try using `composer require "sonata-project/admin-bundle:^3.56" "twig/twig:^2.10"`

Answer (score 2):

We rely on many third party libraries which is hard to fix.

There is also an open issue on GitHub https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/5788

Comment: I know this post is old, but is there an estimated release date for 4.0?